# Embed iFrame in WordPress 3.0.1

Tags: tinymce

I need to embed an iFrame into a post and it appears that tinyMCE or something is stripping it out when I go from HTML to Visual view while editing a post.

I've found instructions for adding valid elements to tinyMCE but it only seems to apply to WordPress 2.8. No such file seems to exist under WordPress 3.0.1 (see [Make WordPress WYSIWYG not strip out iframe's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes))

None of the iFrame embedding plugins seem to support WP 3.0.1 either.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this solution: [Make WordPress WYSIWYG not strip out iframe's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes/3067#3067)?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick - must have missed this part - thanks! Just had to paste the following before the function to make it show up as a plugin: <?php /* Plugin Name: Change tinyMCE Options */

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste this code in your functions.php :

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', create_function( '$a',
'$a["extended_valid_elements"] ="iframe[id|class|title|style|align|frameborder|height|longdesc|marginheight|marginwidth|name|scrolling|src|width]"; return $a;') );
```

This will add a filter to tinymce editor. Working on WP 3.xx

Answer (score 0):

I use tinymce advanced plugin which has the option to not strip iframes in the settings panel.