# Can I stop authors from changing the font in their post?

Tags: author, privileges

I want the site to have a consistent look and feel so want to prevent authors from changing font, font color or font size.

Is there a way to either override their choices, or remove the option?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can deactivate the buttons on [tinymce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes/3067#3067) and html-editor, but the user can than also create html-tags. Then is is also possible you filter `the_content` and replace the font-tags with empty fields.

Answer (score 1):

try and add `!important` to all styles related to the post content that you want to restrict from being changed by the authors; this should force these styles even if somebody uses html tags with inline styles (unless they also use `!important`)
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: Thanks Michael, good advice but unfortunately it didn't work out for me. I'm using a child theme based on Thematic. Will look into it further and hopefully find why it's not working.