# When switching from html to visual editor the <iframe> tag gets corrupted

Tags: tinymce, html, editor, iframe

I'm trying to embed an iFrame, and because I set up some CSS using responsive design, I wish to NOT have `width=""` and `height=""` attributes whatsoever.

When I type this into the HTML editor field..

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1fsm-cvpdfX-8tXauGrQgRmgWONTpX8J3almvZhzBeCA&amp;embedded=true" class="scale-with-grid"></iframe>
```

And then I switch to visual mode and come back, it immediately removes the `class="scale-with-grid"` and changes it to `width="320" height="240"`

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1fsm-cvpdfX-8tXauGrQgRmgWONTpX8J3almvZhzBeCA&amp;embedded=true" width="320" height="240"></iframe>
```

How do I avoid this? I used this "Raw HTML" plugin but it didn't apply to this iframe situation whatsoever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make WordPress WYSIWYG not strip out iframe's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes)

Comment: Please [search the WPSE site for related questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=tinymce+iframe) before posting new questions. This one has been asked and answered several times already.

Comment: I searched with "iframe", "HTML", "visual" while entering the new question. Existing questions with similar strings came up but not that one. Thanks for finding it for me.

Comment: Try using **"tinymce"** when searching for questions related to the visual editor. :)

Comment: [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3067/73) from @bueltge should solve your problem. Does it?

Comment: No dice. Is there a way to DISABLE 'width' and 'height' attributes from that code? I tried removing those attributes and adding 'class' in the mix to create $ext = 'iframe[align|longdesc|name|class|frameborder|scrolling|marginheight|marginwidth|src]'; but with no luck.

Comment: Also note that unlike the previous questions, my problem is not that the <iframe> gets stripped out... but rather, the class="" attribute removed and width/height attributes added automatically, which is the pain. So I do believe that this is, at the end, a totally different question. 

Which begs another question - how is my installation of wordpress allowing <iframe> without the fix above? I didn't make any such changes up until I saw that, and the <iframe> tag itself still worked, albeit with attribute issues.

Comment: Well if anybody else has a constructive feedback other than "This is a duplicate" when it really is a totally different issue, I'd appreciate it. Starting a bounty.

Comment: you can use a plugin to get around the problem... http://www.masternewmedia.org/news/2008/02/22/embed_any_video_or_html.htm is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

On default is the iframe tag a not allowed tag in the editor. You must change the filter for allowed this html tag. Copy the follow source in a plugin and allow iframe for the editor TinyMCE.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_change_mce_options' );
function fb_change_mce_options( $tags ) {

    // Comma separated string od extendes tags
    // Command separated string of extended elements
    $ext = 'iframe[align|longdesc|name|width|height|frameborder|scrolling|marginheight|marginwidth|src|id|class|title|style]';

    if ( isset( $tags['extended_valid_elements'] ) )
        $tags['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    else
        $tags['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;

    return $tags;
}
```

Comment: I think we need `class` attribute more.

Comment: Have you actually tried this in latest WordPress, and was it successful? I can't get this to work with iframes specifically, after adding both `class` attribute and setting `paste_strip_class_attributes` to `none`. it seems iframe is a special case.

Comment: @Milo: yes, you have right. I have tested now and the class attribute was always filtered. But I have not find an solution in the small time frame, where I tested this.

Comment: This problem for `class` attribute is an TinyMCE problem and I dont find an solution; only an custom init in `oninit` param was possible, but this is a great overhead for this requirement.

Comment: I think the solution for allow class on iframes is the embed plugin; maybe little bid to much, id is possible, bute usable; see the [embed plugin](https://github.com/thomasandersen/tinymce-embed-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of an iframe-shortcode. Here's a small plugin to allow that:

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#62729) Shortcode to display an iframe */

function wpse62729_allow_iframes_tinymce( $attr )
{
    global $post;

    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
         'src'          => ''
        ,'width'        => '100%'
        ,'height'       => '100%'
        ,'name'         => md5( $post->post_title )
        ,'scrolling'    => 'no'
        ,'marginheight' => 0
        ,'marginwidth'  => 0
        ,'frameborder'  => 0
        ,'align'        => is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left'
    ), $attr );

    $html = "<iframe";
    foreach ( $attr as $key => $val )
    {
        $html .= " {$key}='{$val}'";
    }
    $html .= "><p>";
    // Message if not possible to display iframe
    $html .= sprinft( 
        'Displaying the iframe is not possible. View the %ssource following this link%s.'
        ,"<a href='{$attr['src']}' target='_blank'>"
        ,"</a>"
    );
    $html .= "</p></iframe>";

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'iframe', 'wpse62729_allow_iframes_tinymce' );
```

Comment: why an shortcode for an default tag, its more to parse the content and stopper for performance? The TinyMCE can iframe, only the class attribute is an problem in the current version, but the id attribute works and is a chance for custom style.

Comment: @bueltge It's just an alternative approach to get around missing (some) support for TinyMCE quickly.

Comment: Yes, this is. But I see many problems of long exists webspace, there use shortcodes for a while and not supportet now.

Comment: @bueltge I'm not sure, if I understood you correctly (just explain it again in german - you can delete it later), but at least it's a plugin.

Comment: yes, a plugin, but the shortcode source is inside the database, inside the content and often I have clients, there not support the shortcodes form older posts.

Comment: @bueltge I complete understand you now. Expect a mail from me.

Comment: This works perfectly fine! Found a plug-in myself actually, had to make minor mods. http://web-profile.com.ua/wordpress/plugins/iframe/