# iframe not showing in post (with "allow php in posts" plugin activated)

Tags: plugins, php

```
$width = 560;
$height = 315;
$code = "I8M_uCnxhwY";

$homepage = "/";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($homepage!=$currentpage) {
echo '<iframe width=".$width." height=".$height." src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$code.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
```

So, that's my current code. I'm trying to display a YouTube embedded video in an iframe within a PHP script that shows said iFrame only if it is not on the home page. (i.e. is a blog post)

If anyone could assist me that would be great.

It seems to acknowledge something should be there, but doesn't show it. I get no errors.

Thanks!

Comment: if i change the echo contents to words like "testing" it works perfectly. what is it about iframes?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that's a quirk with the plugin. In this case, it's better to make a [shortcode](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/02/mastering-wordpress-shortcodes/).

Add this code to your functions.php file:

```
function wpse_77036_embed_video( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'homepage' => '/',
        'currentpage' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        'width' => 560,
        'height' => 315,
        'code' => 'I8M_uCnxhwY',
    ), $atts ) );

    if ( $homepage != $currentpage ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<iframe width="%s" height="%s" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/%s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            $width,
            $height,
            $code
        );
    }  
}
add_shortcode( 'embed-video', 'wpse_77036_embed_video' );
```

You can then use this in your post like:

```
[embed-video width="560" height="315" code="I8M_uCnxhwY"]
```

If no width, height or code is supplied, it will use the defaults as defined in the function. You can also pass a custom homepage or currentpage to the shortcode in the same way you pass the width and height. If you need any more help, please post a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more requirements with iframe, not specific for the YouTube video, then is it also possible, that you allow iframe inside the TinyMCE. See my answer in a older question.

[Make WordPress WYSIWYG not strip out iframe's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes/3067#3067)

But for easy to use the video is the shortcode a nice solution.