# use of <svg> tag into wordpress

Tags: embed, svg

Hi i'm trying to upload a svg map to my wordpress website.

I fixed all to be able to upload svg trough the media gallery but then when i try to write the tag  into the page it won't recognize it. I can only use it embedding it into a  tag... but i can't do that cause i need to work with some svg effect like hover, clicking and so on...

pretty much i would need a way to insert the whole  code with the path and so on, into my page... how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think that WordPress currently not allow the svg tag in his editor. But you can change this, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/make-wordpress-wysiwyg-not-strip-out-iframes/3067#3067) for more hints, background.

I think the follow small source should help you to allow this tag and his attribute. Copy in a plugin (add a plugin header) and activate. But I think, that you enhanced the tags and his attribute. `svg` use a lot of tags, attributes if I see [this example](http://www.html-5.com/tags/svg-tag/index.html#examples).

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_tinymce_add_pre' );
function fb_tinymce_add_pre( $initArray ) {

    // Comma separated string od extendes tags
    // Command separated string of extended elements
    $ext = 'svg[preserveAspectRatio|style|version|viewbox|xmlns],defs,linearGradient[id|x1|y1|z1]';

    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    // maybe; set tiny paramter verify_html
    //$initArray['verify_html'] = false;

    return $initArray;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this solution worked with past versions of WordPress, but as of 6.3.1 it only partially works. If the SVG code is all you enter in the editor, then it will be stripped when you switch to Visual. Prepending/appending any other text/HTML works. I don't know why this is, though.