# Tiny MCE editor stripping xlink:href parameter from SVG USE tag

Tags: filters, tinymce, visual-editor, svg

I have an inline SVG tag with an embedded <USE> tag.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
   <li><svg class="icon-user"><use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use></svg> My Account</li>
</ul>
```

I have created a filter function to force the Tiny MCE editor to leave SVG tags alone. The code was adapted from post: [use of <svg> tag into wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185234/use-of-svg-tag-into-wordpress).

**Filter function:**

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'fb_tinymce_add_pre' );
function fb_tinymce_add_pre( $initArray ) {

   // Command separated string of extended elements
   $ext = 'svg[preserveAspectRatio|class|style|version|viewbox|xmlns],defs,use[xlink:href|x|y],linearGradient[id|x1|y1|z1]';

    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    // maybe; set tiny paramter verify_html
    //$initArray['verify_html'] = false;

    return $initArray;
}
```

I adapted the posted solution to add SVG CLASS, the USE tag and its XLINK:HREF, X and Y parameters.

Problem is the xlink:href parameter is being miss-interpreted resulting in code butchery upon switching to VISUAL mode in the editor.

**HTML before switch to visual mode:**

```
     <svg class="icon-user"><use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use></svg>
```

**HTML after switch to visual mode:**

```
     <svg class="icon-user"><use xlink="href"></use></svg>
```

I have tried escaping the colon in the `xlink:href` function parameter like this: `xlink\:href`, tried an encoded value for the colon like this: `xlink%3Ahref` and using quotes around it like this `"xlink:href"` but all failed.

I know you can embed svg using HTML5 markup, but I would like to try this method if I can get a solution that sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the colon is [a TinyMCE control character](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements)

> Forces the attribute to the specified value. For example, 'border:0'

...hence the switch to `xlink=href`. <strike>The only apparent solution is the wildcard `use[*]`</strike>

Use the control character `?` which "separates attribute verification values" i.e. `use[xlink?href]`

Comment: That's works a treat but gives a lot of freedom to page editors to code other `<use>` tag parameters the site owner might not have wanted. Lucky for me that wasn't the case.  Thanks

Comment: BTW. Using your suggestion and your link I found `use[xlink?href]` worked too and gave benefit of controlling parameters allowed.

Comment: Completely missed that! Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can used js for added  in the beginning of the line

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").prepend('<svg class="icon-user"><use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use></svg>');
});
```

Or assign a class to the li tag